# Cannot find module 'connect' on windows 7

Tags: node.js, npm, connect, windows-7-x64

Please see below:

```
    C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm -g install connect
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/finalhandler/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/1.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/parseurl
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utils-merge/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utils-merge/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/finalhandler/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/parseurl
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/1.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utils-merge/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/parseurl
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/1.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/finalhandler/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-html/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/0.6.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-html/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/0.6.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-html/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/0.6.2
connect@3.1.1 C:\Users\u166824\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\connect
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── parseurl@1.3.0
├── debug@1.0.4 (ms@0.6.2)
└── finalhandler@0.1.0 (escape-html@1.0.1)

C:\Program Files\nodejs>
```

Is my install of Connect module successful? How do I know 'Connect' is properly installed?

Also, when I try to start my server, I get the following error:

```
    C:\Program Files\nodejs>node server.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'connect'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\server.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

And the code in my server.js is as follows:

```
    var connect = require('connect');

connect.createServer(
    connect.static("../angularjs")

).listen(5000);
```

Any ideas why I cannot connect?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't `require()` modules that you've installed with the `-g` flag in npm. Remove the `-g` flag: `npm install connect`. The `-g` is for installing modules that provide command-line utilities, such as the `express-generator` module.

Also, you really shouldn't use `C:\Program Files\nodejs` for your project since npm will install modules in a subdirectory of your current working directory...

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify whether Environment Variable for npm is set properly? [You can check by right clicking my Computer->properties->Advance System Settings tab.

For example DriveLetter:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm