# Cannot find module (nodejs)

Tags: node.js

**Module:**
getmac https://www.npmjs.org/package/getmac

**Backstory:** 
I was using module getmac before and it worked like a charm. Some time ago I updated nodejs to 0.11. And today I tried to use it again. I installed it (npm install get mac) Tried it to use. Nope. "Cannot find module".
I see getmac folder in node_modules. 
`Npm ls` shows:

```
├─┬ getmac@1.0.6
│ └─┬ extract-opts@2.2.0
│   └── typechecker@2.0.8
```

I am using like 20+ other modules without any problems.

**OS:**
Windows 7 32bit, administrator account

**How I test if it work:**
Of possibility that my project can be the issue:

1. I created new folder.
2. Then I open command line and use: `npm install getmac`
3. I created `test.js` with one line: `require('getmac');`
4. In command line: `nodejs test.js`
5. Every time result is the same:

   ```
   module.js:340
       throw err;
             ^
   Error: Cannot find module 'getmac'
       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
       at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
       at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
       at require (module.js:380:17)
       at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Nfq\testo\test.js:1:63)
       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
   ```
6. Others modules works fine

**What I tried:**

- npm install getmac (no errors occurred)
- npm remove/uninstall getmac and  install it again
- npm -g install getmac
- `require('./node_modules/getmac')`
- install from manually downloaded module with different versions 1.04/1.0.5/1.0.6
- node 0.11.13/0.10.32/0.10.25/0.8.27/
- install it in `program  files/nodejs/node_modules`
- delete files in `%appdata%/npm/`
- delete files in `program files/nodejs/node_modules`
- reboot computer several times
- **at virtual machine it works**
- CLI

**error from sublimetext2:**

```
[8036:1014/141615:INFO:CONSOLE(293)] "{"stack":"Error: Cannot find module 'getmac'\n at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:334:15)\n 
"Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'getmac'", source: module.js (336)
```

**File structure of folder node_modules/getmac:**

```
   C:\Users\Nfq\testo\node_modules\getmac
    -   .npmignore
    -   History.md
    -   LICENSE.md
    -   package.json
    -   README.md
    -
    +¦¦¦bin
    -       getmac-node
    -
    L¦¦¦node_modules
        L¦¦¦extract-opts
            -   .npmignore
            -   example.js
            -   LICENSE.md
            -   package.json
            -   README.md
            -
            +¦¦¦node_modules
            -   L¦¦¦typechecker
            -       -   .npmignore
            -       -   cyclic.js
            -       -   History.md
            -       -   LICENSE.md
            -       -   package.json
            -       -   README.md
            -       -
            -       L¦¦¦out
            -           L¦¦¦lib
            -                   typechecker.js
            -
            L¦¦¦out
                L¦¦¦lib
                        extract-opts.js
```

Please help me.

Comment: Have you checked if it works from the CLI?

Comment: try this `sudo npm install getmac -g`

Comment: @mkoryak `sudo` doesn't work on windows

Comment: @razvan I am at administrator account

Comment: @mkoryak Also note that globally installed packages aren't available to `require()` [by design](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski After global install I was trying with `getMac(function(err,macAddress){
    if (err)  throw err;
    console.log(macAddress);    
});` thats proper?

Comment: I found some related questions. They seem to be talking about a environment variable specific to Windows. Might be a lead : [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows) and [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647276/cannot-find-module-connect-on-windows-7)

Comment: @razvan **thank you so much**, **`npm cache clean`** did the job! Thank you man.

Comment: Then I'll add it as an answer. Maybe it will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `node_modules` folder, run `npm cache clean` then reinstall the packages `npm install`.